Asymptotics of negative laplacian eigenvalues
I’ve come across in a paper the fact that the eigenvalues of the negative Laplacian $-\Delta v_k = \lambda_k v_k$ (dirichlet BC, bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$) follow the asymptotic relation
$\lambda_k \sim k^{2/d}$ when ordered in ascending order.
Can anyone provide a reference or proof of this.
Thanks
https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eigenvalue#Weyl_asymptotics

Are you looking for Weyl's law?

https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eigenvalue#Weyl_asymptotics
Looking for a proof of the above

The answers in this question might help.

Thanks this reference sorted it
